# WPF e o Padrão MVVM, dúvidas

Tags: c#, wpf, design-pattern, mvvm

To estudando C# e estou tendo que desenvolver uma aplicação WPF com o padrão MVVM. Uma dúvida que tenho sobre esse padrão é em relação aos eventos, já li em alguns lugares que não é recomendável utilizar eventos e também que não podemos acessar componentes diretamente, por meio da viewmodel.

Mas tem situações que precisamos realmente acessar elementos da view, para isso eu criei uma interface contendo os métodos que preciso, implemento ela na view e conecto ela a viewmodel. Assim eu não acesso os elementos diretamente, essa seria uma boa solução?

```
// interface
public interface IWindowServices
{
    void ToggleWindow();
    void MinimizeWindow();
    void ExitWindow();
}
```

E então na view:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E sobre os eventos, eu realmente devo evitar? Estou em uma situação onde preciso permitir que ao clicar 2x sobre um elemento da view, a suas propriedades mudem...